# how should i store lists of lists in MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to store this list of lists but I don't know how to store it in MySQL

```
list[x][y] the items in this list contains {li:[{x:x,y:y}] , pos:{x:y}}

list[x][y].li[z].x
list[x][y].li[z].y
list[x][y].pos.x
list[x][y].pos.y
```

for better undersing, please have a look at this[image: this]

edited:[image]

is this right? so this means i will only have 2 tables?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: could you check my conceptual schema?@Glains

Comment: It depends what you intend to do with it. If you're literally just dumping it in there for storage and your application deals with the data itself then something like throwing it into a JSON/BSON column (Postgres would be better for this) is probably fine. If you want to be able to query on the data effectively then breaking it up into several relational tables is going to be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a separate table with sub-lists that have a column *parent_id*, and then a third table with actual list items of low level lists.

The query for this will look like this:

```
SELECT li.x, li.y, sl.id
FROM li_items li  
JOIN sub_lists sl on li.list_id = sl.id
JOIN lists l on sl.parent_id = l.id;
```

The process of converting the result rows depends on if you use some ORM or plain mysql client.

You could also store it as a JSON, as deleted answer has suggested, but than you wan't be able to query specific items without selecting and parsing all the lists. You could also use MySQL's JSON column, but In your case having separate tables seems to be better

Comment: Having master-detail tables is the right approach. Storing JSON is against the best practices of database design. See here for DB normalization: https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php